# sudo apt-get install -f is not working

Tags: apt, skype

I tryed to install Skype and then this http://pastebin.com/e9VxKFwN
Website works fine,I rebooted but it still does not work I also imported their certificate.Is there anything I can do?

Here's the poignant part of the error:

```
Err https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/ trusty/main libdrm2 i386 2.4.56-1
  Failed to connect to download.01.org port 443: Mreža je izvan dosega
Err https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/ trusty/main libdrm-intel1 i386 2.4.56-1
  Failed to connect to download.01.org port 443: Mreža je izvan dosega
E: Failed to fetch https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/libd/libdrm/libdrm2_2.4.56-1_i386.deb  Failed to connect to download.01.org port 443: Mreža je izvan dosega
```

Comment: Hmm, you're the third person reporting something like this today. I think there might be an issue with intel's SSL/TLS certificate.

Comment: Is there way to revert this until Intel fixes problem?

Comment: Are you able to use another repo?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean,other repos work fine.

Comment: Have you tried activating Multiverse and Canonical repositories,